# Get input text by xPath

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

I try to write autotest using C# and Selenium framework, but I can't get text of an input field. 
The html of the element:

```
<input id="WorkPlacePageEmployerKPPcb96e63d-c837-4e7f-827b-2e7d49370f20TextEdit-el" class="base-edit-input ts-box-sizing" placeholder="Empty" value="" style="" tabindex="1" disabled="disabled" type="text">
```

In my browser I see that it has some text inside, but the following code

```
inputElement.Text
```

returns empty string. `inputElement` is of `OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement` type.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please attach some screenshot or provide the text which is visible in browser? if text is 'Empty' in browser follow my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<input type="text">` has no text content, but attribute `"value"` that changes after user send keys

Try to replace

```
inputElement.Text
```

with

```
inputElement.GetAttribute("value")
```

Also you might use `JavaScriptExceutor` for this purpose:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
string inputText = (string)js.ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].value", inputElement);
```

Comment: same thing. Field with text inside has empty value.

Comment: Try to implement `JavaScript` as in updated answer. You might also try to wait until input value changed with explicit wait

Comment: `inputElement.GetAttribute("value")` works for me. But when I inspect inputElement in Browser (firefox) it has empty value as I told my it start post. Why cant I see value attribute in Browser?

Comment: It's hard to tell what's the problem without seeing actual web-page

Answer (score 1):

It seems visible text is 'Empty' on browser which is visible to you. Please use below code to fetch the text visible on browser:

```
inputElement.GetAttribute("placeholder")
```

Also you might use `JavaScriptExceutor` for this purpose as suggested by @Andersson:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
string inputText = (string)js.ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].placeholder", inputElement);
```